# Kernel of $\psi: U_{24} \to U_4 \times U_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Consider $\psi: U_{24} \to U_4\times U_6$ such that $\psi(x)=(x,x)$. Determine its kernel.

To determine its kernel, I wrote that:
$\psi(x)=(\bar{1}_{4},\bar{1}_{6})\iff (x,x)=(\bar{1}_{4},\bar{1}_{6}) \iff x \equiv 1 \mod 4 \land x \equiv 1 \mod 6 $, so $4|(x-1) \land 6|(x-1)$, but this happens iff $\ $$lcm(4,6)|(x-1) \iff 12|(x-1)$, then $ker(\psi)=\{\bar{1}_{24},\bar{13}_{24}\}$. Is this a good argument?

Comment: Your argument is fine.